# Wordpress camcelCase in shortcode attributes

Tags: wordpress, shortcode

It says here :

IMPORTANT – Don’t use camelCase or UPPER-CASE for your $atts attribute names:

$atts values are lower-cased during shortcode_atts( array( 'attr_1' => 'attr_1 default', // ...etc ), $atts ) processing, so you might want to just use lower-case.

https://developer.wordpress.org/apis/handbook/shortcode/

My question is does this means I can still safely use camelCase in shortcode attributes? (since my vars come in this format) Later before shortcode output I replace underscore vars with camelCase.

Comment: No, do not use camelCase for the attribute `names`. Your vars can be whatever you want them to be. Basically, you don't want the user to do this `[shortcode_name camelCaseAtt=""]` You could also reassign your `vars` to lowercase versions if you are concerned.